# How to use BETWEEN clause in Kohana ORM

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-db

I am new to kohana. I am using ORM for getting data.

I want to build a query in which `BETWEEN` clause is there. as following

```
SELECT `rooms`.* FROM `rooms` LEFT JOIN `events` ON (`rooms`.`id` = `events`.`room_id`) 
WHERE `events`.`room_id` IS NULL 
OR (`events`.`eventstart` NOT BETWEEN 1312210800  AND 1312218000)
```

for that i am doing the following

```
    $rooms = $room->join('events', 'LEFT')
                  ->on('rooms.id', '=', 'events.room_id')
                  ->where('events.room_id', 'IS', NULL)
                  ->and_where_open()
                  ->or_where('events.eventstart' , 'NOT BETWEEN', $from)
                  ->and_where_close()
                  ->find_all();
```

But i am getting the the query like this

```
SELECT `rooms`.* FROM `rooms` LEFT JOIN `events` ON (`rooms`.`id` = `events`.`room_id`)
WHERE `events`.`room_id` IS NULL AND (`events`.`eventstart` NOT BETWEEN 1312210800)
```

Can someone point out how to use BETWEEN clause

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should use `or_where('events.eventstart', 'BETWEEN', array($from, $to));`
Documentation on Kohana Query Builder can be found here -> http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/database/query/builder
ORM uses Query Builder.

Comment: try `or_where('events.eventstart', 'NOT BETWEEN', array($from, $to));`

Comment: it might be worth asking on the kohana forums and/or filing a feature request.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I've found that works reliably is to use `DB::expr()`.

Consider the following:

```
or_where('events.eventstart', 'NOT BETWEEN', DB::expr('1312210800  AND 1312218000'));
```

Or you can stick it all in variables:

```
$range = "{$from} AND {$to}";
or_where('events.eventstart', 'NOT BETWEEN', DB::expr($range));
```